Vault secret fetch using hvac python fails with TypeError where Type of response is <class 'requests.models.Response'>
I am trying to login to Vault using token auth & fetch the credentials from secret/data/my-secret-path
#Reading secrets from the path secret/data/my-secret-path where secretpath = 'my-secret-path' without secret/data
Using Vault with KV Version 2 secret engine mount
import hvac

vault_address = 'my-vault-address/namespace=my-namespace'
vault_token= 'my-secret-token'
client = hvac.Client(url=vault_address, token=vault_token)
print(client.is_authenticated()) -> Returns true 
secretpath = 'my-secret-path' 
secrets = client.secrets.kv.read_secret(secretpath)
secret_cred = secrets['data']['secret']
print(secret_cred)

Getting the below error because of "secret_cred = secrets['data']['secret']"

TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable

Tried with
secrets = client.secrets.kv.v2.read_secret_version(path=secretpath, mount_point='secret',raise_on_deleted_version=True)
secret_cred = secrets['data']['secret']
print(secret_cred)

Got the same error

TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable

Saw same issue mentioned in https://github.com/hvac/hvac/issues/538
TYPE:
type(secret_cred) is <class 'requests.models.Response'>
Have also tried several ways to fetch secret from secret_cred like which was not fruitful,
secret_cred.get("data")
secret_cred.json()
json.loads(secret_cred.content)
json.loads(secret_cred.text)

Any guidance to fetch the secret from the type "requests.models.Response" would be really helpful

Hi Ruby, welcome to Stackoverflow! Help us help you by adding to your question the output of type(secret_cred). (do not post as an answer to this comment).

Thank you for the response - @ixe013. I have updated my question with the type of my output

Thanks, but wrong variable... The problem starts with type(secret_cred). StackOverflow is async and low bandwidth. Awful for debugging. Take your time to formulate a good question, it is worth it.

@ixe013, Sorry for that. I have updated.

It looks like you have Vault Enterprise, and that you are using a namespace called my-namespace.
To use an enterprise namespace with Vault, pass it using the namespace parameter when you create your hvac client, instead of passing it as the URL:
import hvac

vault_address = 'http://localhost:8200'
vault_namespace = "my-namespace"
vault_token = 'root'

client = hvac.Client(url=vault_address, token=vault_token, namespace=vault_namespace)

Then to retrieve the secret, you must index data twice. The second data index has a sibling metadata index that you might need someday.
Append this code to the previous:
secretpath = 'my-secret-path' 

secret_cred = client.secrets.kv.read_secret(secretpath)
secret_cred_latest = secret_cred['data']['data']['secret']
print(secret_cred_latest)


secret_cred_latest = secret_cred['data']['data']['data']['secret'] worked thank you!
